# Default font in outlook

Tags: outlook, group-policy, automation, outlook-2003

What's the best way, and easiest, to change our estate's default font in outlook?  Do the office .adm files allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after loading the adm, you can specify the settings in User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Microsoft Office Outlook

Answer (score 0):

use this link 
https://www.ntweekly.com/2014/10/29/how-to-configure-outlook-2013-font-using-group-policy/

How To Configure Outlook 2013 Font Using Group Policy